# Prevent redux fetch hook from contacting the server if a condition is not met

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I created useFetchLocationsQuery hook using createApi of Redux. The hook calls server that returns names of cities matching the query string. If the query is blank (for example if the app loads or if user clears the search field) I need to prevent the hook from contacting the server but don't know how to do it. Please advise.

```
import { Autocomplete, Button, Grid, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { useFetchLocationsQuery } from '../store';
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

export function AddLocationComponent() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const {data } = useFetchLocationsQuery(query);
  const options = (data || []).map(p => p.name);

  const changeHandler = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedEventHandler = useMemo(() => debounce(changeHandler, 2000), []);

  const renderInput = params => {
    return <TextField {...params} onChange={debouncedEventHandler} label="With categories"/>
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={10}>
            <Autocomplete
                options={options}
                renderInput={renderInput}
                onInputChange={debouncedEventHandler}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `skip` option, or `skipToken`:

```js
  const {data } = useFetchLocationsQuery(query, { skip: someCondition });
```

```js
  import { skipToken } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
  const {data } = useFetchLocationsQuery(someCondition ? skipToken : query);
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like useFetchLocationQuery should be called unconditionally at the top level of yoru component. you can use useEffect hook:

```
import { Autocomplete, Button, Grid, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { useFetchLocationsQuery } from '../store';
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

export function AddLocationComponent() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  
  const { data } = useFetchLocationsQuery(query);

  const changeHandler = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedEventHandler = useMemo(() => debounce(changeHandler, 2000), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (query) {
      // Fetch data only when query is non-empty
      // Update options based on the fetched data
      setOptions((data || []).map(p => p.name));
    } else {
      // Reset options when query is empty
      setOptions([]);
    }
  }, [query, data]);

  const renderInput = params => {
    return <TextField {...params} onChange={debouncedEventHandler} label="With categories" />;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <Autocomplete
            options={options}
            renderInput={renderInput}
            onInputChange={debouncedEventHandler}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this generates following error: "React Hook "useFetchLocationsQuery" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render"